# How to dereference a string pointer

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm having issues getting the desired behaviour out of my code. I'm new to the C language (although I usually program in C++ so I'm sort of familiar), and I'm unsure where to go with my issue. In the below code, when attempting to populate the 2 strings with the contents of the "input" string passed to the function, the result is that the memory locations are passed to the 2 strings, meaning when I perform modifications on the individual strings, the original data is edited... I want to have it such that the initial data is copied to the new memory locations allocated to the new strings.

```
bool interpretInput(char *input)
{
    char *name = malloc(MAX_NAME_SIZE / 2);
    char *surname = malloc(MAX_NAME_SIZE / 2);

    if (name == NULL | surname == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    int length = (int) strlen(input);
    if ((length > 0) && (input[length - 1] == '\n')) input[length - 1] = '\0';

    if (surname = strpbrk(input, " "))
    {
        int sLength = (int) strlen(surname);

        for (int i = 0; i < sLength; i++)
        {
            surname[i] = surname[i + 1];
        }

        length = (int) strlen(input);

        for (int i = 0; i <= length - sLength; i++)
        {
            name[i] = input[i];
        }

        length = (int) strlen(name);
        sLength = (int) strlen(surname);

        printf("Name: %s length: %d \n", name, length);
        printf("Surname: %s length: %d \n", surname, sLength);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Name length: %d", length);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I, effectively, want to populate one array with the values at each increment of another array, without using strcpy.

Comment: You leak memory, you miss to do `free`. Also `if (surname = strpbrk(input, " "))`  - you meant to `==` ?

Comment: also... `if (name == NULL | surname == NULL)` ==> `if (name == NULL || surname == NULL)`. One | is bitwise or, two ||s is logical or.

Comment: @KamilCuk No I want to assign strpbrk() to surname if it exists, which is what the implementation does... And yes the code is incomplete, which is why the free() hasn't been implemented yet...

Comment: Why have you deleted all the text of the original and replaced it? None of the answers or comments make any sense anymore

Comment: please do not vandalize your post; I've rolled back the edits.

Comment: `if ((length > 0) && (input[length - 1] == '\n')) input[length - 1] = '\0';` is better written as `input[ strcspn( input, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `strcpy(char* dest, char* src)`. Dereferencing a char* will simply yield you the first char in the string.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char* test = "hello world";
    char* test2 = malloc(11*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(test2, test);

    printf("%s\n", test);
    printf("%s\n", test2);
    test2[5] = '_';
    printf("%s\n", test);
    printf("%s\n", test2);
    printf("%c\n", *test);

    free(test2);
}
```

spits out

```
hello world                                                                                                                                                                        
hello world                                                                                                                                                                        
hello world                                                                                                                                                                        
hello_world                                                                                                                                                                        
h
```